# Cannot create QEMU virtual disk through command line

Tags: command-line, qemu

My problem when making a QEMU virtual disk is that it doesn't let me create it.

I discovered this when I wanted to install Windows 98 build 1702 on QEMU and load QEMU through the command line.

I navigated to the folder where QEMU is installed, I typed the following command:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 win.img 2G
```

It was creating the virtual disk.

Aaaand... that's what I got:

```
qemu-img: win.img: Could not create 'win.img': Permission denied
```

I had no idea what caused this and why I cannot make QEMU virtual disk through the command line. So if possible, I need to know what causes this problem and how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I use VMware and not QEMU.   Are you sure QEMU supports Windows 98?  Windows 95 and Windows 98 do not run without special mods on modern and fast machines

Comment: @John Qemu supports *wa-a-ay* more things than VMWare. For example, it can run ARM, MIPS, etc. virtual machines on X86-64 hardware and vice versa, so you can run virtual Raspberry Pi. It is no problem for it to run any X86 virtual machines on X86-64 hardware, as if there are i386, i486, Pentium and so on CPUs. And, by the way, the question was not about what it supports to run inside VM, but about running Qemu itself on the host.

Answer (score 0):

It attempts to create image file in the current directory — the one you had navigated to, where Qemu binaries are installed. Your user account is not permitted to write there, and you get the "permission denied" error.

You need to navigate to directory where your user is able to create files, and specify the full path to the qemu-img binary:

```
cd C:\Users\MyUser\MyVM
C:\Program Files\...\qemu-img.exe -f qcow2 win.img 2G
```

This works better if you add Qemu binary directory to the PATH environment variable. You'll then be able to invoke Qemu binaries without typing the full path to the binary, from any directory. Then always invoke them from the target VM directory.

OR you can navigate to the directory where Qemu binary is (as you did), and specify the full path to the new image file where you actually have permissions to create files:

```
cd C:\Program Files\...\
qemu-img.exe -f qcow2 C:\Users\MyUser\MyVM\win.img 2G
```